# Properties of least common multiple

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

If $a$ and $b$ are integers, the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, written as $[a,b]$, is defined as that positive integer $d$ such that

(i) $a\mid d$ and $b\mid d$

(ii) Whenever $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$ then $d\mid x$.

Prove that $[a,b]$ exists and that $[a,b]=ab/(a,b)$, if $a>0, b>0$.

**Proof:** Let $S=\{k\in \mathbb{N}: a\mid k \ \text{and} \ b\mid k\}$ and since $ab\in S$ then $S\neq \varnothing$. Thus the set $S$ has minimal positive element. Let's call it $c$ and we'll prove that $c=[a,b]$. It is easy to verify that $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$, so the first property is true. Taking any $x\in S$ and by remainder theorem $x=cq+r$ where $0\leqslant r <c$. Since $r=x-cq$ and $x\in S, c\in S$ then $r\in S$. Since $c$ is the minimal positive element in $S$ then $r=0$. Thus $c\mid x$. Indeed, $c=[a,b]$.

Now we are ready to prove that $[a,b]=ab/(a,b)$. Denote $N=ab/(a,b)$ and it's easy to chech that:

1) $a\mid N$ and $b\mid N$.

2) If $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$ then $x=at_1,\ x=bt_2$. Then:$$x=at_1=\dfrac{ab}{(a,b)}\cdot \dfrac{(a,b)}{b}t_1=N \dfrac{(a,b)}{b}t_1$$ 
Let's consider two cases:

2.1) If $(a,b)=1$ then from $t_2=\dfrac{at_1}{b}$ we get $b\mid t_1$ in that case $N\mid x$.

2.2) If $(a,b)=d>1$ then $\left(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d}\right)=1$ then $t_2=\dfrac{at_1}{b}=\dfrac{a/dt_1}{b/d}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{b}{d}\mid t_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $b\mid dt_1$ and since $x=N\dfrac{(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})dt_1}{b}$ we see that $N\mid x$. Thus, we have shown if $a\mid x, \ b\mid x$ then $N\mid x$ where $N=\dfrac{ab}{(a,b)}$. So $\dfrac{ab}{(a,b)}=[a,b]$

Is it correct?

Comment: Tags: [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification)?

Comment: Your proof is complete until the last line. I think you'll need to finish the last line to make it a proof. Otherwise, it looks fine to me.

Comment: @stressed-out, edited

Comment: @RFZ: Yes. Now it seems almost complete. However, if we want to be strict, you haven't shown $N=x$ yet. You have only shown that $N | x$ which implies nothing because you didn't mention in your assumptions that $x$ was taken to be "a" L.C.D. You need to mention that you were assuming $x$ to be "a" L.C.M and you also have to prove that L.C.M is unique. Therefore, it makes sense to talk about "the" LCM of two numbers.

Comment: @stressed-out, What? I have shown that $N$ is lcm of numbers $a$ and $b$. Two properties are true. Showing that $N=x$ is meaningless. Take a look more carefully

Comment: @stressed-out $x$ is not lcm. I was showing that if $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$ then $[a,b]\mid x$

Comment: @RFZ: How do you know that LCM(a,b) is unique? :) Maybe two numbers can have two different LCM's? I know that it's not possible. I'm just saying that you need to prove that LCM is indeed well-defined for two numbers. That point is missing, I guess.

Comment: @stressed-out In the first part of proof when I was working with the set $S$ I showed that lcm is minimum of this set. Hence it's unique.

Comment: @RFZ: Yes. You're right that $x$ is not the LCM of a and b. Sorry for that. But you still need to show that $N$ is equal to the LCM of a and b. Just because it satisfies the properties of the LCM it doesn't mean that it has to be equal to it. What if LCM is not a well-defined concept? You haven't shown that the LCM of two numbers is uniquely defined. That's what I meant. **EDIT:** And yes, because you have defined as the minimum, and the minimum of a set is unique, then it's unique. I just wanted to say that the proof is unclear why $N$ is the LCM without knowing the uniqueness.

Comment: @stressed-out, What is your definition of greatest common divisor of numbers $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @RFZ: I'm using your definition. Your definition is the standard one. Maybe I'm being too sensitive, but I think that you still haven't accepted why the uniqueness of the LCM matters in your proof and Stefan's proof. Check Stefan's proof and read my answer to your question under his post.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems to be correct, but it's lengthy. You can use the fact that $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, s.t. $(a,b) = ax + by$. Assume that $m$ is a common multiple of $a,b$ then:

$$\frac{m}{N} = \frac{md}{Nd} = \frac{m(ax + by)}{Nd} = \frac{max}{ab} + \frac{mby}{ab} = \frac{mx}{b} + \frac{my}{a}$$

But the RHS is obviously an integer, therefore $N \le m$, so $N$ is the least common multiple of $a,b$

Comment: How do you conclude from $N\leqslant m$ that $N$ is lcm?

Comment: @RZF: $m$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. And we have shown that $N$ is smaller than any common multiple of $a$ and $b$ and it is a common multiple of them. Therefore, it's the least one. Because if there was another common multiple, namely $N'$, then $N' | N$ and since they're positive, $N' \leq N$. But because $N'$ itself is a common multiple, that gives $N=N'$. That's what I meant by the uniqueness property.

Comment: @RFZ Well the name of it is *least* common multiple. If $N$ is less than any common multiple and $N$ itself is a common multiple of $a,b$ then we have $N = [a,b]$